# Barcode Reader for 3G

Tags: iphone, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am newbie to iPhone application. But recently I saw a post asking for Barcode Reader for 3G iPhones. And people(including me) have referred to [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/#svn/trunk/iphone) which works on 3GS or later and if you want to make an appication for 3G then better you buy it from QuickMark or RedLaser to get 3g scanning.

So I planned something and need several information from you all

There are lots available on appStore. One of them is pic2shop(Which is a free application).
But what I want to know is:
What exactly is it done to recognize the barcode and generate code?
Is there any website or link to which when image of barcode is send will respond with the code generated or any API which does the same i.e. Taking picture and generating code.

And Secondly From Where does we get the information about the produce related to that barcode code.

Comment: 24 views and still not even a single comment or answer :O

Answer (score 0):

Hi we recently had a product which required bar code scanning functionality, in the end after evaluating a lot options we went with zBar but it does not work on iPhone 3G it requires 3GS or above.

zBar is an open source SDK you can download it from sourceforge.

What we're doing right now is scanning bar codes using the zbar SDK & then calling upcdatabase.com API through xml-rpc to get the information about the product back.

And its working pretty well.

If you do not want to pay redlaser or others for SDK I would recommend using this approach. But of-course the downside is iphone 3G is not supported which I think does not represent many devices & also recently Apple has also dropped its support for its upgrades as iPhone 3G users will not be able to upgrade to iOS 4.3.

I actually own a 3G iphone & its very slow on iOS version 4.0 .

Comment: Thanks @Asad Khan... I have the same problem that I too have a 3G iPhone. And Since iPhone 4 is not launched in India.. Cant go for it yet :( .... But I dont want to use the readymade SDK. I want to create one.. So need to know what kinda image processing is done. :)

Comment: Then I would recommend you to look at the zBar source code... Open of the few luxuries of open source projects...And zBar works on 3GS & above

Comment: In zBar, I am facing issues with iPad - landscape orientation. Is there any solution for that?