# How to add barcode reader functionality for iPad application?

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am not aware whether any library available for barcode reader functionality for iPad application. (Using iPad2's camera)

Please provide some documentation links.

Comment: You may want to check this answer for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667832/barcode-reader-for-3g Possibly a dupe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used [savvy](http://shopsavvy.mobi/developers/) or [scandit](http://www.scandit.com/).

OR

if you want to go with the open source -[zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/iphone) is the best one for iOS.

Comment: Mayur Birari: Which one you suggest as better one? Requirement is - It should be work over both iPhone & iPad, for both the orientations.

Comment: I tried Savvy on an iPod touch 4th gen and without luck. My guess is that it's the fixed-foced camera, which is why ZBar doesn't work on the iPod touch or iPads.

Comment: Also, Zxing for iOS only supports QR codes. Not the standard 1-D barcodes.